# Server error 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied when accessing any page with HTTP

Tags: plesk, windows

We migrated our website to new windows server with Plesk Obsidian 18 and noticed that we are not able to access website without HTTPS
example

`http://www.example.com/test.html` NOT WORKING
ERROR Message

```
Server Error

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

`https://www.example.com/test.html` WORKING

Any pointer what could be the reason as Plesk redirect setting look good

Comment: There are tons of possible reasons why you might get a forbidden message.  Anything from a server mis-confiugration to a file permissions problem.  Have you looked in your server's error log to see if it has extended information?

Comment: Yes i looked at server log it was returning 403 error for page i was trying to access. anyways issue was resolved and added as a solution just in case someone else may face similar issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the resolution as issue was resolved based on below article

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003646494-A-website-hosted-in-Plesk-for-Windows-Server-is-not-accessible-over-HTTP-when-Require-SSL-TLS-IIS-setting-is-enabled-HTTP-Error-403-4-Forbidden

To make the website accessible over HTTP, disable the Require SSL/TLS IIS option:

```
in Plesk

    Log in to Plesk.

    Disable Require SSL/TLS option at Domains > example.com > IIS Settings > Directory Security Settings and apply the changes.

in IIS Manager

    Connect to the Plesk server via RDP.

    Disable Require SSL option in IIS Manager at Sites > example.com > SSL Settings and apply the changes.
```